Cech cochain from principal parts of $x \in S$
Let $S$ be a Riemann surface. A principal part of $x \in S$ is a Laurent series, valid in a neighborhood of $x$ of the form $$P=\sum_{k=1}^n a_kz^{-k},$$ with $a_k \in \Bbb C$ and $z$  a local coordinate for $x$. Let $x_1,\dots,x_d \in S$ and $P_1,\dots,P_d$ be the principal parts. Show that $P_1,\dots,P_d$ can be used to form an element $P \in C^1(\mathcal{U},\mathcal{O})$ for an open cover $\mathcal{U}$ of $S$ such that $$\delta (P)= 0.$$
For $\delta(P)$ to be zero we need $$\delta(P)_{ijk} = P_{jk}\vert_{U_i\cap U_j \cap U_k} - P_{ik}\vert_{U_i \cap U_j \cap U_k} + P_{ij}\vert_{U_i \cap U_j \cap U_k} = 0.$$
Pick an open cover $\{U_j\}$ such that $z$ is a valid coordinate around $x_j$. If we define $P_{ij} = P_j$ if $i = j$ and $0$ else, the coboundary operator should vanish and we get what we want? I'm confused as we do not use any properties of the principal part here?

$P_j$ is not holomorphic at $0$, so if $x_j$ is mapped to $0$ in $U_j$, then this will not suffice.
